# JPA: How to map a Map with Date as key

Tags: java, date, jpa, dictionary, persistence

Normally you'd map a Date as `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` and you'd map a Map<> as `@ManyToMany` or `@Lob`.

Now I am trying to map a Map. I have tried `@ManyToMany @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` but this doesn't seem to work:

```
Exception Description: The type [class java.util.Map] for the attribute [x] on the entity class [y] is not a valid type for a temporal mapping.
```

So my question is, how to map a Map containing a Date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
 @OneToMany
 @MapKeyTemporal(DATE)
 protected java.util.Map<java.util.Date, Employee> employees;
```

Comment: Thanks! `@MapKeyTemporal` was indeed the one I needed. I have edited your answer though, since `@ElementCollection` was needed due to the use of `Float` as value.