# How to Map a Ternary Map of Dates With a Bidirectional Relationship?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, collections, orm

I've read: [JPA: How to map a Map with Date as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859569/jpa-how-to-map-a-map-with-date-as-key) but I have the opposite of the question, I have the value component of the `Map` as a Date. How should I map this? Map: `Map<Club, java.util.Date>` Can you show an example including the code for the Club class? It should be noted that this is a ternary mapping. I'm not sure if this matters or not, but `Club` and `Clubber` also have a bidirectional `ManyToMany` relationship. My initial guess was this:

```
public class Clubber{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "Clubber_Id")
   private final int id;
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   @ElementCollection
   @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
   private final Map<Club, Date> joinDate;
   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private final Collection<Club> clubs;
}

public class Club {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "Club_ID")
   private final int id;
   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "clubs")
   private final Collection<Clubber> clubbers;
}
```

Main:

```
Map<Club, Date> dates = randomGeneration(Date.class);
Collection<Club> clubs = randomGeneration(Club.class);
Clubber clubber = new Clubber(clubs, dates);
Club club = new Club(Arrays.asList(clubber));
session.saveOrUpdate(club);
```

The Exception I get when I try to save a `Club` with a few `Clubbers` in it:

```
 org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Club
```

The moment I add an `@Transient` to the `Clubber`'s `joinDate` the exception disappears.

Comment: So what do you want? Do you want to know why that exception is coming and how to solve it or something else..

Comment: @Amogh Yes, how to solve it.

Comment: can you post the code block where you save the `Club`?

Comment: @Amogh Updated. I'm thinking that the save should be cascaded, so saving the `Club` should be good enough, but that's not the case?

Comment: have you gone through the article which I given? try implement saving logic as described in that article, I think that can solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your entities should look like:

```
@Entity(name = "Clubber")
public class Clubber{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Clubber_Id")
    private Integer id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="CLUB_ASSIGNMENTS", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Clubber_Id", referencedColumnName="Clubber_Id"))
    @Column(name="CLUB_DATE")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "Club_ID", referencedColumnName="Club_ID")
    private Map<Club, Date> joinDate = new HashMap<>();

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Map<Club, Date> getJoinDate() {
        return joinDate;
    }

    public Collection<Club> getClubs() {
        return joinDate.keySet();
    }

    public void addClub(Club club) {
        joinDate.put(club, new Date());
        //clubs.add(club);
        club.getClubbers().add(this);
    }
}

@Entity(name = "Club")
public class Club {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Club_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "joinDate", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Clubber> clubbers = new ArrayList<>();

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<Clubber> getClubbers() {
        return clubbers;
    }
}
```

These are the tables this mapping generates:

```
create table CLUB_ASSIGNMENTS (Clubber_Id integer not null, CLUB_DATE timestamp, Club_ID integer not null, primary key (Clubber_Id, Club_ID))
create table Club (Club_ID integer generated by default as identity (start with 1), primary key (Club_ID))
create table Clubber (Clubber_Id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1), primary key (Clubber_Id))
alter table CLUB_ASSIGNMENTS add constraint FK_i1d8m16i8ytv7jybg8aneo9hj foreign key (Club_ID) references Club
alter table CLUB_ASSIGNMENTS add constraint FK_6oitm1mry43ga5iovtfamp3q3 foreign key (Clubber_Id) references Clubber
alter table CLUB_ASSIGNMENTS add constraint FK_3xj613grja6o0xkjeb7upms4 foreign key (CLUB_DATE) references Club
```

This is how you associate a `Clubber` to a `Club`:

```
final Clubber clubberReference = doInTransaction(session -> {
    Clubber clubber = new Clubber();
    Club club = new Club();
    clubber.addClub(club);
    session.persist(club);
    return clubber;
});

doInTransaction(session -> {
    Clubber clubber = (Clubber) session.get(Clubber.class, clubberReference.getId());
    assertEquals(1, clubber.getClubs().size());
    assertEquals(1, clubber.getJoinDate().size());
});
```

I created a test on [GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-master-class/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/hibernate/masterclass/laboratory/mapping/ManyToManyWithElementCollectionTest.java) to check this and it works:

```
insert into Club (Club_ID) values (default)
insert into Clubber (Clubber_Id) values (default)]
insert into CLUB_ASSIGNMENTS (Clubber_Id, Club_ID, CLUB_DATE) values (1, 1, '2015-06-10 16:37:36.487')
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the exception tells that while saving a `Club` object list of `Clubber` (Collection clubbers) is not saved. The code where you are saving Club, before saving `Club` you have to save each `Clubber` in it then call `save` for `Club`.

Applying @Transient annotation is used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted in the database. that's why you are not getting exception after applying `@Transient`.

Comment: @Amough That kind of sounds like I should add a `@Cascade` somewhere. Can you post the code for how you would change the annotations? Or do I just have to manually save each `Clubber`?

Comment: @SarahSzabo Yes, you can do cascade insert as you already added `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`. That's why I asked to update the code you used for saving `Club` but didn't update question. Anyways have a look to this example for `@ManyToMany Bidirectional` https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-manytomany-unidirectional-bidirectional/